# TexNicCenter problem using \footcite

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to create foot citations in my document. However I keep getting the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'A01' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 23.
```

The output I get for the footcite is "A01". Since for some reason if doesn't associate the book info with A01 although it is right there.

The example I am trying to use is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=150pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text.\footcite{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to compile your document with `biber` as well. Did you?

Answer (score 1):

TeXnicCenter has no prebuild profile for compiling LaTeX and biber.

Press Alt+F7, copy an existing one (`LaTeX => PDF`), rename it to `LaTeX => biber PDF` and change the call for `bibtex` to `biber`, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\bibtex.exe
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\biber.exe
```

Now change in TexnicCenter the compiling method from `LaTeX => PDF` to the new `LaTeX => biber PDF` and compile three times.

That should it be, if there are no other problems ...